# Maven Changing Java Compiler

Tags: java, maven

When updating my maven project, the java compiler is changing from 1.7 to 1.5.

this is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.chart.simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>core Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>core</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Help!!

Comment: check to make sure that in your path system property, Java correctly points to java 7

Comment: It seems your Spring version is incompatible with Java and pulling out v1.5 from repositories - that's of course only if you have checked your JAVA path etc. correctly.

Comment: it is correctly set. I have 1.7 in build path, 1.7 in compliance and 1.7 is facets

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't specify an explicit version, you get the default.

While it might look like setting `java.version` is doing something to select a particular JVM, it isn't.  It's just a name bound to a value.  Maven can't switch JVMs after it is invoked, so you are probably overwriting the original value (which was probably `1.5`).  Keep in mind that if you have Java 1.5 installed, if it's before the other JVMs it will get invoked first.  Also, you can have "maven specific" settings in any "maven launching" scripts, and other such items.

Configure your compiler plugin [like so](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).  Set a source and target version.  Also, keep in mind that Maven doesn't "include" a compiler, so it will do it's best to configure the installed compiler to fit your declared source and target settings.

Comment: Actually, you do get a particular version.  Version 1.5.  That's what the Maven docs say.

Comment: You're right, I'm just so used that version being very old.  Will update question.

Answer (score 1):

The default compiler source and target level for Maven is 1.5.

> "Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the default target setting is 1.5, independently of the JDK you run Maven with. If you want to change these defaults, you should set source and target as described in ["Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)."

Source:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

---

One reason that your attempt at setting "java-version" property has no effect is that "java-version" is not one of the recognized Maven built-in properties.  This page lists the built-in properties that are available:

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide

Note that though there is a "java.version" property, it is an (effectively) read-only that reports the java version of the JVM that is running Maven.  It doesn't control the Java compiler source and target levels.

Answer (score 0):

Add the compiler plugin

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I usually put the above on the parent POM that way any projects under it which are JAR/EAR/WAR projects will use 1.7 without triggering the plugin as part of the build.

If you have a solitary JAR module just get rid of pluginManagement to keep things simpler.